# Field of meromorphic functions

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $A, B$ and $C$ be compact Riemann surfaces with non-constant holomorphic maps $f: A \rightarrow C$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$, such that fields of meromorphic functions are isomorphic $M(A)=M(B)$ over $M(C)$. How to prove that $A$ bihilomorphic to $B$?

Update: I mean, how to prove it purely via Riemann surfaces? It should follow from the fact that degree of map is equal to degree of extension, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Each of your Riemann surfaces has a unique structure of a smooth projective algebraic curve and for such a curve $A$ the field of meromorphic functions reduces to the field of rational functions: $M(A)=\text {Rat}(A)$.

This is the most elementary example of a general principle discoverd by Serre and affectionately named GAGA [it  has nothing to do with a certain Lady singer, despite question 4) of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/60273/450)]

Hence $M(A)=M(B)$ implies $\text {Rat}(A)=\text {Rat}(B)$.
An amazing theorem of the algebraic geometry of curves then implies that the algebraic curves $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic because their rational function fields are isomorphic, and so *a fortiori* are their underlying Riemann surfaces:  $A$ is indeed isomorphic to $B$ in the category of Riemann surfaces .
Notice that your Riemann surface $C$ and your morphisms $f,g$ haven't been used at all!